# List of Ranges Used in SQL Expression, Creates "Invalid SQL Statement" Error

Tags: python, list, range, arcpy

I'm trying to use a list of ranges in a SQL expression within my Python script, but whenever I try and run it, it gives me the following error.

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used. [PatientVisitsGeocoded]
An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT ObjectID FROM PatientVisitsGeocoded WHERE USER_CenterID = 1001 AND USER_MonthsSinceFHOpening = (1, 3)]
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass)
```

However, when I use only one range, instead of a list of ranges, the script runs fine.

I had a hard time finding examples of lists containing ranges, and I developed the syntax for my list from the best answer on this page:

[Python List with ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469145/python-list-with-ranges)

I don't know if the syntax for my list of ranges is just wrong or if I need to change the way my expression is constructed. Any advice/help would be much appreciated.

Here is my full code:

```
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps6.gdb"

#Declare variables
fc = 'Open_GoHealth_Centers'
fields = ['USER_market_id','USER_GoHealth_ID','USER_GoHealth_Center_Name','USER_Opening_Date', 'USER_MonthsSinceFHOpening']
fieldname = 'USER_market_id'

# Set Markets to loop through
markets = [1000]
# Set Years to loop through
years = [2014, 2015]
# Set Ranges to loop through
myranges = [(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]

sqlclause = (None, 'Order By USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')

for market in markets:
    print (market)
    #Define WHERE clause statement
    whereclause = """{} = """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname)) + str(market)

    for year in years:
        print (year)
        for myrange in myranges:
            print (myrange)
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields, where_clause=whereclause, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')) as cursor:
                #Loop through each row established in cursor
                for row in (cursor):
                    # Set local variables for the FeatureClasstoFeatureClass tool
                    inFeatures = "PatientVisitsGeocoded"
                    outLocation = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps6.gdb"
                    outFeatureClass = "PatientVisits{0}_{1}_{3}".format(row[0], row[2], myrange, year) 
                    delimitedfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"USER_CenterID")
                    expression = """{0} = {1} AND USER_MonthsSinceFHOpening = {2}""".format(delimitedfield, row[1], myrange) 
                    print (expression)

#                   Execute FeatureClassToFeatureClass tool
                    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureClass, expression)

#                   #Print Results
                    print(row[2])
                    print(year)
                    print(myrange)
```

Comment: It should be `In (1,3)`  not `= (1,3)`

Comment: @Andy G Thanks! That fixed the error, but now I am only getting data for the first and last numbers in the range and not all the numbers in between. So instead of getting data for 1, 2, and 3 I only get it for 1 and 3.

Comment: Then you want `Between 1 and 3` not `In (1, 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `In (1, 3)` not `= (1, 3)`.

If you want the range between the values 1 and 3 then use `Between 1 and 3`. `In` means "match one of these values", it isn't inclusive.

Comment: So if I want to use BETWEEN then do I also need to change my list from `myranges = [(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]` to `myranges = [(1 and 3), (1 and 4), (1 and 5)]`?

Comment: No. That would be invalid syntax anyway. When you construct the SQL statements you need to extract the values of the tuple `myrange[0]` and `myrange[1]` and insert them into the appropriate positions in the expression `Between x and y`.